# what would be the solution by using Hensel's Lemma?, p-adic numbers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

Point out the main difference or relation between Newton's polygon and Hensel's lemma when it comes to find solution of the two variable  polynomial  $ f(x,y)=y^6-5xy^5+x^3y^4-7x^2y^2+6x^3+x^4=0$.

$ \text{Using Newton's polygon}:$

Plot the points (exponents $(a,b)$) as given below:

$(6,0), (5,1), (4,3), (2,2), (0,3), (0,4)$.

The plot is given below:

[image]

Thus the vertices of the Newton polygon  are $ \ (0,3), \ ( 2,2), \ (6,0)$.

The line segment joining these points is $ \ x+2y=6$.

Now the monomial s corresponding to the vertices $ \ (0,3), \ ( 2,2), \ (6,0)$  are

$y^6-7x^2y^2+6x^3=0, .......(1)$.

This can be solved easily.

Divide the equation $(1)$ by $x^3$ both sides,

$ \frac{y^6}{x^3}-7 \frac{y^2}{x}+6=0$

or, $ Y^6-7Y^2+6=0$, where $ \ Y=\frac{y}{\sqrt x}$,

This can be written as

$ (Y^2-1)(Y^2-2)(Y^2+3)=0 \\ \Rightarrow Y=\pm 1, \ \pm \sqrt 2, \ \pm \sqrt{-3} . $

i.e., $ y=\pm \sqrt x, \ y=\pm \sqrt {2x}, \ y=\pm \sqrt{-3x}$.

These are the solutions by using $ \text{Newton Polygon}$.

**But what would be the solution by using Hensel's Lemma?**

**What would be the difference?**

Please help me using Hensel's lemma and pointing out the difference or relation in both method.

Comment: $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x,y], g(x,y ) = \partial_x f(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x,y]$. Given $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $A \bmod p$, if $f(A \bmod p,b \bmod p) = 0 \bmod p$ and $g(A \bmod p,b \bmod p) \ne 0 \bmod p$ then you can find $a \in A+p\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(a,b)=0$ and that $a$ is unique.

Comment: @reuns, Please give a short answer so that I will get you. As i am new to this topic, I will not get by hints.

Comment: Well look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

Comment: @reuns,  This was my old post. Can you explain why did you only take $g(x,y)=\partial_x f(x,y)$ ? what about the other derivative $f_y(x,y)$ ?  Did you fix $y$ ? Shouldn't we take the gradient in case of multi-variable ?